# Is is safe to re-use McDonalds Lego Happy Meal Cups?

Tags: food-safety, drinks, plastic, sanitation

Over the last couple of years, we have accumulated several McDonalds [Lego Happy Meal Cups](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mcdonalds%20lego%20cups&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjypbmhsJLVAhXJBcAKHXBIBs8Q_AUICygC&biw=1902&bih=707) from [this release](http://www.thebrickfan.com/the-lego-movie-mcdonalds-action-cups-review/) and other releases.

We have been re-using them for drinks, both warm and cold and putting them in the dishwasher.

I believe that they are made up of [#7 plastic](http://www.thebrickfan.com/the-lego-movie-mcdonalds-action-cups-review/), which contains BPA.

[BPA](http://www.webmd.com/children/bpa#1) has been linked to some health concerns, hence some products proudly state they are 'BPA Free'.

So, is our current practice safe, or should we bin them/ only use them for play?

Comment: This is just opinion, not an answer, but I think reusing disposable plastic utensils is a very bad idea.